# Creating User Accounts with unique uid in OpenLDAP

Tags: unique, account, openldap, uid

I'm trying to create a number of user accounts (class is OpenLDAPperson) in OpenLDAP and the problem I'm having is that the uid property is not enforced as UNIQUE by LDAP.

Looks like only object class "account" enforces uid uniquenes, unfortunately, I cannot seem to combine it with object classes like OpenLDAPperson or OrganizationalPerson.

Can anyone recommend a best practice for creating users and have uid uniqueness also enforced in LDAP?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem and switched to OpenDJ(formerly OpenDS). It supports unique index on UID.